# I don't understand how the prompts work in llama_index

Tags: langchain, huggingface, large-language-model, llama-index, vector-database

I have been trying to query a pdf file in my local directory using LLM, I have downloaded the LLM model I'm using in my local system (GPT4All-13B-snoozy.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin) and trying to use langchain and hugging face's instructor-large model for embedding purpose, I was able to set the service_context and then building index but I'm not able to query , I keeping getting this error regarding prompt..

> ValueError: Argument `prompt` is expected to be a string. Instead found <class 'llama_index.prompts.base.Prompt'>. If you want to run the LLM on multiple prompts, use `generate` instead.

I'm just starting to learn how to use LLM, hope the community helps me....

[error message part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TuW0.png)

[error message part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOcAX.png)

```
from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex, SimpleDirectoryReader
from InstructorEmbedding import INSTRUCTOR
from llama_index import PromptHelper, ServiceContext
from llama_index import LangchainEmbedding
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain.llms import OpenLLM
# from langchain.chat_models.human import HumanInputChatModel
from langchain import PromptTemplate, LLMChain
from langchain.llms import GPT4All
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(r'C:\Users\avish.wagde\Documents\work_avish\LLM_trials\instructor_large').load_data()

model_id = 'hkunlp/instructor-large'

model_path = "..\models\GPT4All-13B-snoozy.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin"

callbacks = [StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]

# Verbose is required to pass to the callback manager
llm = GPT4All(model = model_path, callbacks=callbacks, verbose=True)

embed_model = LangchainEmbedding(HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name = model_id))

# define prompt helper
# set maximum input size
max_input_size = 4096
# set number of output tokens
num_output = 256
# set maximum chunk overlap
max_chunk_overlap = 0.2

prompt_helper = PromptHelper(max_input_size, num_output, max_chunk_overlap)

service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(chunk_size= 1024, llm_predictor=llm, prompt_helper=prompt_helper, embed_model=embed_model)

index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents, service_context= service_context)

query_engine = index.as_query_engine()

response = query_engine.query("What is apple's finnacial situation")
print(response)
```

I have been going through, the source code of the library as the error message guides but I couldn't find the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have written here is a little old/erroneous. But the main error is the service context setup with `llm_predictor=llm`. You can just pass the llm in directly as a kwarg.

Using the latest version (v0.7.22 at the time of writing) I would re-write your service context like so:

```py
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
    chunk_size= 1024, 
    llm=llm, # this is updated
    prompt_helper=prompt_helper, 
    embed_model=embed_model
)
```

Source: https://gpt-index.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core_modules/model_modules/llms/usage_custom.html#example-changing-the-underlying-llm

For reference, if you pass in an llm from langchain like this, the service context detects this and wraps it with our langchain wrapper for you:

```py
from llama_index.llms import LangChainLLM

llm = LangChainLLM(langchain_llm)
```

This is useful to know, since other parts of llama-index (agents, chat engines, etc.) my expect an LLM object as the input, and won't wrap it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot your suggestions worked!! but now the response it is giving is "ERROR: The prompt size exceeds the context window size and cannot be processed.ERROR: The prompt size exceeds the context window size and cannot be processed."

Comment: Answered over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76873456/error-the-prompt-size-exceeds-the-context-window-size-and-cannot-be-processed/76876933#76876933