# GPT4All prompt size

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain, gpt4all

Name: gpt4all
Version: 2.0.2

I am trying to query a database using GPT4All package using my postgresql database.
Below is the code

```
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
from langchain_experimental.sql import SQLDatabaseChain
from langchain import SQLDatabase
from langchain.llms import GPT4All
import os

username = "postgres" 
password = "password" 
host = "127.0.0.1" # internal IP 
port = "5432"
mydatabase = "reporting_db"

pg_uri = f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{mydatabase}"
my_db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(pg_uri)

PROMPT = """ 
Given an input question, first create a syntactically correct postgresql query to run,  
then look at the results of the query and return the answer.  
The question: {question}
"""

path = "./models/mistral-7b-openorca.Q4_0.gguf"

callbacks = [StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]

llm = GPT4All(model = path,
              callbacks=callbacks,
              n_threads=3,
              max_tokens=5162,
              verbose=True
             )


db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm = llm, 
                     db = my_db,         
                     verbose=True
                     )

question = "Describe the table Sales"
answer = db_chain.run(PROMPT.format(question=question)
                     )
print(answer)
```

but I am getting the following error,

```
ERROR:  sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at 
or near "ERROR"
LINE 1: ERROR: The prompt size exceeds the context window size and c...
    ^

[SQL: ERROR: The prompt size exceeds the context window size and cannot be processed.]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)
```

Is there a parameter I should change in order to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76866751/i-dont-understand-how-the-prompts-work-in-llama-index). It seems gpt4all itself cant adjust max token of models.